# Testing node-amqp using mocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, amqp

I have a node service which uses AMQP to perform a remote procedure call, so it publishes a messages to a given amqp exchange and expects a response on a given amqp queue with the results of that call.

I am looking for a good unit test strategy which mocks the amqp connection can send a message based on a given input. I have looked into amqp-mock module but this seems to require a connection to a real amqp server and this was something I wanted to avoid.

Has anyone implemented anything similar or have a good strategy for this?

Answer (score 1):

You easily mock require by using the ["a" module](https://npmjs.org/package/a):

```
// Example faking require('./foo') in unit test:
var fakeFoo = {};
var expectRequire = require('a').expectRequire;
expectRequire('./foo').return(fakeFoo);

// in sut:
var foo = require('./foo'); // returns fakeFoo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give [node-amqp-mock](https://github.com/rstuven/node-amqp-mock) a try.

Comment: Note that it's way outdated now, doesn't run on recent node versions.

Comment: 4 years later, do we have better options testing rabbitmq client code with mocks ?